# High level - interpreted language in C89

Tags: interpreter, c89

I need any high level language interpreter written in C89.   What are my options?

I would like to take the language and possible extend it to support some of the low level OS dependent functionality of the host platform.

The interpreted language can be any high scripting style style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking, what I wanted was an extension language.  The strongest contender is Lua.

There is a nice discussion here:  [here](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/04/01/05/2143227/lightweight-scriptingextension-languages)